# Project Management list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

May I find help in how can I manage my projects and its tasks in sharepoint 2010.

each project has 4 phases each pahse has start date and end date, in addition muli tasks .
each task linked to phase and to project name.

could you please lead my to right way to build this customized system ??

appreciated to your support .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is much too vague. The most simple answer would be a Task List, with 2 lookups to a Project Phase list and a Project Name list. Voila!

Use a Task List linked to MS Project?

Comment: Seamless Teamwork:  http://www.amazon.com/Seamless-Teamwork-SharePoint%C2%AE-Technologies-Collaborate/dp/0735625611         SharePoint for Project Managers:  http://www.amazon.com/SharePoint-2010-Project-Management-Raymond/dp/1449306373/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1341170260&sr=1-1&keywords=sharepoint+project+managers